# Qswat in newer version of QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation, hydrology, qswat

How can I setup `QSWAT` in newer versions of `QGIS` ? The [link here](https://swat.tamu.edu/software/qswat/) says `QSWAT` requires `QGIS 2.6`. I tried installing `QSWAT` in new versions and it couldnot be done.
Is there a way to install `QSWAT` in new `QGIS` may be `version 3` or so.

Comment: Apparently, no way for QGIS 3. Even for greater version than QGIS 2.8

Comment: so does that mean I'm stuck with 2.6 forever? @KadirŞahbaz

Comment: Seems like the QSWAT Google Group would know if there is or ever will be a new version of QSWAT. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US#!forum/qswat

Comment: New version at https://swat.tamu.edu/software/plus/